# fread fails to read an unsigned int? [C]

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I have a `Person` Struct as the following:

```
typedef struct Person {
    char name[NUM_CHARS];
    unsigned int age;
} Person;
```

where `#define NUM_CHARS 20`.

I want to write this structure to a binary file, so I wrote two function to handle that:

```
int writePerson(Person* person, FILE* _fp) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen(person->name);
    // Write name
    for(i = 0; i < len+1; i++) {
        count += fwrite(&(person->name[i]), sizeof(char), 1, _fp);
    //  fseek(_fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    // Continue
    // Write age
    count += fwrite(&(person->age), sizeof(unsigned int), 1, _fp);

    return count;
}

int readPerson(Person* person, FILE* _fp) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    // Write name
    for(i = 0;person->name[i] != NULL;i++) {
        count += fread(&(person->name[i]), sizeof(char), 1, _fp);
    }
    // Continue
    // Write age
    count += fread(&(person->age), sizeof(unsigned int), 1, _fp);

    return count;
}
```

So I wrote a `Person` to a blank file `Px.bin` that I've created well in advance:

```
int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("Px.bin", "r+b");
    Person person = {"Billie", 40};
//  Person y ;
    int x = writePerson(&person, fp);
    printf("%d", x);
//  printPerson(&y);
    getchar();
    fcloseall();
    return 0;
}
```

Seems to work well, prints `8`.

but when I try to read this file:

```
int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("Px.bin", "r+b");
//  Person person = {"Billie", 40};
    Person y ;
    int x = readPerson(&y, fp);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printPerson(&y);
    getchar();
    fcloseall();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this result:

```
11
Billie
-858993460
```

Where printPerson is:

```
void printPerson(Person* p) {
    printf("%s\n%d\n", p->name, p->age);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You might want to change the comments in `readPerson` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit

```
for(i = 0;person->name[i] != NULL;i++) {
    count += fread(&(person->name[i]), sizeof(char), 1, _fp);
}
```

is going to use uninitialized (IOW, containing garbage) `person->name[]` as the condition for reading. And it may so happen that the wrong number of bytes will get read here.

After that the following

```
count += fread(&(person->age), sizeof(unsigned int), 1, _fp);
```

can read the integer from an incorrect location within the file, not where said integer has been stored.

The fix would be to first read a character and then see if it's `'\0'` or not. If it is, the string's been fully read. If it's not, keep reading characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that reads name does check for likely non-initialized (or zeroed out) `person->name[i]` elements. As result the loop end at some non-predictable time (i.e. if it is zeroed out loop will not `fread` even single character).

```
for(i = 0;person->name[i] != NULL;i++) {
    count += fread(&(person->name[i]), sizeof(char), 1, _fp);
}
```

You want to change it to `do`/`while` loop or instead of reading till `0` prefix data in the file string with length and read that many characters.